# The stream is currently in use by a previous operation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, textwriter

I am running to the below issue and unable to workaround it

https://andrew.thomas.net.nz/c%23/2020/08/30/Beware-of-using-File-Stream-WriteLineAsync-methods/

I am unable to workaround it since await can't be included inside lock and do not want to use async-lock implementations so looking for your thoughts to help me fixing this issue with a simple solution.

Comment: Do you mean you need an async lock? There are plenty implementations out there, just google and pick one.

Comment: I know, but is there an easier way to fix this issue without locking the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer, If you don't want to use any signal or lock that might be impossible to avoid the problem.

To avoid that thing you need to control your thread access resource, otherwise, you might encounter the race-condition problem.

if you don't want to use `lock` there is another way to control thread access resource at the same time [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-6.0)

We can set the value `initialCount` & `maxCount` by 1 from `SemaphoreSlim` which represents that only one thread can use the resource others will wait for the signal at the same time when you are using multiple threads.

```
private static SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);
           
await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
//your want to avoid race-condition code zone.
semaphoreSlim.Release();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot scape from using [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-6.0). That's because the abstraction of a stream is sequential access. Why do you want to WriteLines in a file in not sequential access?